# Set Default Value for Select by using value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cgi

I have web page with dynamically created Selects (dropdown), the web page created by shell CGI script:

```
while read line; do  
  textBoxValue=`printf "$line" | cut -d'        ' -f1`
  comboBoxValue=`printf "$line" | cut -d'       ' -f2`

echo "  
  <div id="divId$start_id">
    <input type="text" name="newTexdtBox$start_id" id="newTextBox" value='$textBoxValue' /> 
    <select name="newComboBox$start_id" id="newComboBox" value="$comboBoxValue">
      <option disabled>pls select</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="9">all</option>
    </select>
    <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='return removeThisElement($start_id)'>Remove This</a> 
  </div>
  <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='return getSelects()'>getSelects</a>

  "

  start_id=$((start_id+1))
  count=$((count + 1))
done < my_conf
```

Each Select object has his own attribute value=$comboBoxValue. I would like to set this value attribute as selected when page loaded. Suggested solution is (http://snipplr.com/view/67752/set-default-value-for-select-dropdown-lists-using-value-attribute/) but it seems dont work because this.getAttribute("value") doesnot return anything.

How I can set Default Value for Select (dropdown list) by using value attribute?

Comment: it looks like your making multiple selects dynamically. you should make the id's match the name attribute so that you don't end up with multiple elements with the same id , that can cause you all kinds of greif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution http://snipplr.com/view/67752/set-default-value-for-select-dropdown-lists-using-value-attribute/ is working properly, I just forgot \ symbol when render function from Shell script  (getAttribute(\"value\")).

This works fine (when rendering from CGI Shell script):

```
\$(document).ready(function() {
  \$('select[value]').each(function(){  
    \$(this).val(this.getAttribute(\"value\"));        
  });                                                 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<select name="newComboBox$start_id" id="newComboBox" value="$comboBoxValue">
      <option value="" selected='selected'>pls select</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
```

Comment: each time when page loaded the selected value can be different therefore I can not use "selected='selected'" option in this case

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve it using jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('select[value]').each(function(){
        $('option[value="' + $(this).attr('value') + '"]', this).prop('selected', true);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CdWbD/)

But the optimal solution will be to solve it using html markup itself. (I don't know cgi scripts), but something like

```
<select name="newComboBox$start_id" id="newComboBox">
    <option disabled>pls select</option>
    <option #if ($comboBoxValue == 1) { selected="selected"} value="1">1</option>
    <option #if ($comboBoxValue == 2) { selected="selected"} value="2">2</option>
    <option #if ($comboBoxValue == 3) { selected="selected"} value="3">3</option>
    ....
</select>
```

Comment: Got error Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: option[value= + $(this).attr(value) + ]

Comment: looks like you are missing the `'` and `"`s